# Dynamically initialize enum based on associated value

Tags: swift, enums, mirror

This is my enum:

```
enum E {
    case a(Int), b(String)
}
```

**The enum's associated value types are unique and always exactly one.**

Let's say I have this variable:

```
let myInt = 0
```

I want to create an instance of `E`, based on variable `myInt`, **dynamically**. This should result in:

```
E.a(0)
```

But in the 'real world', I don't know what property I get. I only know one thing: I can initialize enum `E` with it. I need to dynamically initialize the enum, based on a property value. I currently have a huge switch on the property to initialize the enum, I don't want that.

But I have no idea how to accomplish this task. I tried mirroring the enum type, but I get a complex type and I have no idea how to proceed initializing it even if I know the types.

So I get a property of a certain type. I know that certain type matches a case in enum E, because there is exactly one case which associated value corresponds to the property type. I want to initialize an instance of that enum with that case, with the value of the property.

Comment: I'm unclear as to why you can't get write one initializer for each case and have it construct the corresponding case and associated value.

Comment: Swift doesn't have the reflection capabilities necessary to do this yet. Some third party libraries add in such support, but  Iwouldn't even bother tbh. Just use the `switch`.

Comment: Is there any json or decoding involved?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Nope, in the app we do the same as in the example I provided, but with more cases

Comment: @JoshHomann I don't want to write unnecessary/derived switch statements/code. There is enough information to initialize the enum IMO

Comment: can you provide some *real world* examples please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom initializer: (I have used more descriptive names)

```
enum TypeFinder {
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
    case unknown(Any)

    init(value: Any) {
        switch value {
        case let v as Int: self = .int(v)
        case let v as String: self = .string(v)
        default: self = .unknown(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
var unknownTypeValue: Any = "Testing.."

print(TypeFinder(value: unknownTypeValue))

unknownTypeValue = 1234

print(TypeFinder(value: unknownTypeValue))

unknownTypeValue = true

print(TypeFinder(value: unknownTypeValue))
```

Comment: I stated in my question that I want it dynamically (even bolded) and I already mentioned that I have a switch at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

If your only starting point is the type of what will eventually be an associated value, you can use a `switch` statement:

```swift
enum E {
    case a(Int)
    case b(String)

    init(associatedValue: Any) {
        switch associatedValue {
        case is Int:
            self = .a(associatedValue as! Int)
        case is String:
            self = .b(associatedValue as! String)
        default:
            fatalError("Unrecognized type!")
        }
    }
}

let response = E(associatedValue: 1) // .a(1)
let other = E(associatedValue: "haha!") // .b("haha!")
```

The problem here is this switch must be exhaustive, meaning cover *all* types. So you either need a dumping ground case (`.unreachable(Any)`) or a `fatalError` so you can catch these in development.

Comment: I stated in my question that I want it dynamically (even bolded) and I already mentioned that I have a switch at the moment.

Comment: You mean you want the compiler to figure out what you have automatically. a) as someone mentioned that's not really possible in Swift and b) even if it were, it doesn't make any sense in Swift. You can have two cases that _both_ have the same associated value type: `case a(Int), case b(Int)`. Now if you get an `Int`, which is the appropriate one?

Comment: And one last comment, if each type is guaranteed to only be used once, just use the type itself! You gain nothing by "dynamically" wrapping your types in an enum that just describes the type.

Comment: 'as someone mentioned that's not really possible in Swift' so because someone on the internet says something isn't possible, the truth is that it isn't possible? I know what reflection can do in Java, so I thought maybe I can dynamically find the matching case in runtime, rather than statically typing out the switch. I gain nothing? Well, I hope I don't gain more code! I hope I lose code when I can Mirror the case myself. Anyway, thank you for your effort.

Comment: My comment regarding gaining nothing is that if you wrap your types in an enum that just describes the type, you're _still_ writing a switch statement, a switch statement when you want to _unwrap_ the type. So you "dynamically" create an enum to avoid writing a switch, but you still have to write a switch, because it's an enum. Get it now?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do something like that

```swift
enum E: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    
    case a(Int), b(String)
    
    init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self = .b(value)
    }
    
    init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {
        self = .a(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: I confirm this solution works, it allows you to write such thing `let test:E = 10` instead of having to write `let test:E = E.a(10)`